# warning : return makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures, stack

```
struct Stack {
    char top;
    unsigned capacity;
    char* array;
};   
char*pop(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(stack)){
        printf("Stack underflow\n");
     
    }
        return  stack->array[stack->top--];
}
char* peek(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(stack)){
      printf("Stack underflow\n");
    }else{
    return stack->array[stack->top];
}}
```

> 

```
***main.c:56:29: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]                                                    
main.c:67:24: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

I have these two warnings and I can't deal with them, I need help, please

the warnings are in these two lines :

```
 return  stack->array[stack->top--]......
 return stack->array[stack->top]
```

Comment: Either the return type or the type of the member `array` is wrong. It is unclear which is expected without the context.

Comment: If the type of `array` is correct, the functions should return `char` because the elements of the array pointed at by `array` is `char`. If the return types are correct, the member `array` should be `char**`.

Comment: Sidenote: `peek()` doesn't return anything from the `if` branch.

Comment: I changed the array type to char** and the two warnings gone .. but another warning in other function called push  came out .. this is the function and the warning :               
 void push(struct Stack* stack, char* item)
{
    if (isFull(stack))
       printf("Stack Overflow\n");
    else {
      stack->array[++stack->top] = *item;
    }                              assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change both the function return types to `char` instead of `char*` since `stack->array[stack->top]` is going to return a character and not a `char*`

Also, on a side note, your `peek()` doesn't return anything from the `if` branch. Change that to return something ( a dummy character as per your program logic) or just make it a standalone `if` statement like the one in `pop()`.

Comment: I tried to change the functions types but it didnt work ....I changed the array type to char** and the two warnings gone .. but another warning in other function called push came out .. this is the function and the warning : void push(struct Stack* stack, char* item) { if (isFull(stack)) printf("Stack Overflow\n"); else { stack->array[++stack->top] = *item; } assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: and thank  for your note about peek function

Comment: @Rama If I understand correctly, you want to create a stack of strings? That would make sense why changing the return type to `char*` fixed the warnings. Coming to `push()`, you are assigning a `char` to a `char*` in the statement `stack->array[++stack->top] = *item;` because `item` is a `char*` (a character array) while `*item` is a `char`. That's the the reason you get that warning (which is the _reverse_ of the one you originally asked in the question).

Comment: yes you understand correctly ... so , what should I do to get red of the final warning ... and thank you

Comment: @Rama Since you need to keep a copy in the stack, doing a simple `stack->array[++stack->top] = item` won't be safe. Use  something like [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) to create a copy of the incoming `item` and do `stack->array[++stack->top] = strdup(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear. You're trying to return an integer instead of a pointer.

`stack->array[stack->top--];` is the element in the array `stack->array` at position `stack->top--`

So change `return stack->array[stack->top--];` to just `return stack->array;`

Or change the return type to `char` instead of `char*` depending on what you want to achieve.